# Is this bad practise creating indexes using all columns in include?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I have a table and I am creating non-clustered indexes on fields which are used frequently in search in where clause. I am creating indexes using include clause and put all fields inside that.

Ex:

```
Create NonClustered Index IX_DocumentDate on Documents
(
    DocumentDate     
)
Include(
    JurisdictionID,
    JudgementTypeID,
    IDate,
    EfileDate,
    UserID,
    RecordingDateTime,
    ApprovedBy,
    ACEfileBankAccountID,
    LastStatusChangedDateTime,
    ACEfileCreditCardID,
    EfiledByUserID,
    ITypeID,
    IGroupID,
    InstrumentID,
    OldInstrumentID,
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    CreatedByAccountID,
    [DocumentStatusID]      
      ,[Remarks]
      ,[InternalNotes]
      ,[ParentDocumentID]
      ,[FilingNumber]
      ,[StampData]      
      ,[Receipt]
      ,[ReceiptNo]
      ,[IsReEfiled]      
      ,[ImportedFromInstrumentID]
)
```

As against just creating indexes. These fields are all used in `Select`. Just wanted to know am I doing it wrong? I get huge performance bonus when I do it like this. If this is okay, then why did Microsoft not use it as default option and include all fields of table in `include`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In general, in SQL, it is always bad to have one pattern - a LOT depends on the usage and that will vary.

In the above case this may or may not be wise or needed or beneficial. Do NOT forget you pay a price - in disc size (=IO and more RAM usage) as well as in update and insert speed (slower).

Generally, INCLUDE should be used cautiously. Start without, then use it where you have problems and it helps.

Comment: Thanks TimTom. Speed is more critical to me than disc size at this point. It took nearly 5 seconds when I created simple indexes and it now takes 0 seconds when I do pagination and get records between 80000 and 80050.

Comment: well, that can be it or can not be - could also be a problem with your memory size. So, yes, in this case it helps, but your question was "always". It is not used as a default option because it really has HUGH price - in your case it seems to make sense, but it is bad as a general option. Same with compression and a lot of other features. One reason I dont like "model first" approaches (Entity Framework) - there are tons of tuning parameters in the database. One has to be able to set them.

Answer (score 3):

You are storing your entire table twice, once in the index, once in the main table.  This is generally regarded as a waste of space.  It also reduces the efficiency of the index; there is more data to read than there would be if you restrained yourself to no included columns, or only a few included columns. It might well be sensible to include the primary document ID column in the index (though it is not clear which column is the primary document ID), but the majority of the columns you included are clearly superfluous to the index.

So, the reason it isn't the default behaviour is because it is not as efficient as an index without included columns.  So, don't include any columns in the index until you have a need to do so, and can measure that it improves the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clustered Index for one column, may be with primary key and then check performance. You can compare the performance of clustered index against indexes with all column. 
The best practice says you should have minimum indexes as per requirement.